# How to sort by multiple keys with some of them in descending order

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
a = [
  { :id => 10, :name => 'bush' },
  { :id => 2, :name => 'sugar' },
  { :id => 10, :name => 'mountain' },
  { :id => 10, :name => 'bug' },
  { :id => 8, :name => 'sugar' }
]
```

I would like to sort the array by id ascending numerically first, and then by name descending alphabetically so the end result would be:

```
a = [
  { :id => 2, :name => 'sugar' },
  { :id => 8, :name => 'sugar' },
  { :id => 10, :name => 'mountain' },
  { :id => 10, :name => 'bush' },
  { :id => 10, :name => 'bug' }
]
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Names are important. Names in dynamic languages are even more important, don't use `a` for a collection, use a plural. For example: `hs`/`hashes`/`items`/....

Answer (score 4):

Based on the edit made to your question, to do a traditional sort you would use

```
a.sort { |a, b| [a[:id], a[:name]] <=> [b[:id], b[:name]] }
=> [
  {:id=>2, :name=>"sugar"},
  {:id=>8, :name=>"sugar"},
  {:id=>10, :name=>"bug"},
  {:id=>10, :name=>"bush"},
  {:id=>10, :name=>"mountain"}
]
```

You can switch the sort order by swapping your conditional check.

```
a.sort { |a, b| [a[:id], b[:name]] <=> [b[:id], a[:name]] }
=> [
  {:id=>2, :name=>"sugar"},
  {:id=>8, :name=>"sugar"},
  {:id=>10, :name=>"mountain"},
  {:id=>10, :name=>"bush"},
  {:id=>10, :name=>"bug"}
]
```

Comment: This is awesome, fun to see how the comparison operator works with arrays !

Comment: I like this, it shows ruby is such a powerful and succinct language!

Comment: Oh, that is very nice, thank you. That is a great tip. I was about to post the longer version with the same code that Zack posted, but this is certainly simpler. For a short array like this it wouldn't matter, but I wonder if the longer version of the code might be faster for a large array, though. The longer code doesn't have to construct two arrays for each comparison and only has to compare the `:id` fields in the case where the ids are different. So it would seem that it should be faster for a large array.

Answer (score 1):

a.sort {|a,b| (a[:id] != b[:id]) ? a[:id] <=> b[:id] : b[:name] <=> a[:name] }

```
>> a
=> [{:id=>10, :name=>"bush"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"sugar"}, {:id=>10, :name=>"mountain"}, {:id=>10, :name=>"bug"}, {:id=>8, :name=>"sugar"}]
>> a.sort {|a,b| (a[:id] != b[:id]) ? a[:id] <=> b[:id] : b[:name] <=> a[:name] }
=> [{:id=>2, :name=>"sugar"}, {:id=>8, :name=>"sugar"}, {:id=>10, :name=>"mountain"}, {:id=>10, :name=>"bush"}, {:id=>10, :name=>"bug"}]
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @DanReedy's answer is superb for clarity, but it may have performance issues if you're applying it to large lists due to making a lot ( O(N logN) of small intermediate arrays and repeated hash lookups.  `sort_by` can help by making the sort keys once O(N) to be reused in the O(N logN) comparisons.  To accomplish the descending ordering of the secondary key, we need a way to reverse the ordering of the comparison method.

```
module DescendingComparable
  def <=>(other)
    - super
  end
end

pry(main)> a.sort_by {|e| [ e[:id], e[:name].dup.extend(DescendingComparable) ] }
=> [{:id=>2, :name=>"sugar"},
 {:id=>8, :name=>"sugar"},
 {:id=>10, :name=>"mountain"},
 {:id=>10, :name=>"bush"},
 {:id=>10, :name=>"bug"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a pattern that's been around for years:

```
class SortByInverter < Struct.new(:value)
  def <=>(other)
    other.value <=> value
  end
end

class Object
  def desc
    SortByInverter.new(self)
  end
end
```

And now let's use it:

```
hs.sort_by { |h| [h[:id], h[:name].desc] }
```

Of course we can use directly the container class (more verbose but without scary extensions to `Object`):

```
hs.sort_by { |h| [h[:id], SortByInverter.new(h[:name])] }
```

Comment: @sawa I have a hard time calling globally extending `Object` with a short-named method "cleanest".

Comment: @dbenhur: Nobody forces you: `hs.sort_by { |h| [h[:id], SortByIntervert.new(h[:name])] }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
a.sort do |a1, a2|
  comparison = a1[:id] <=> a2[:id]
  (comparison != 0) ? comparison : a1[:name] <=> a2[:name]
end
```